# Adding coordinates into exit geojson file ruins my whole map(D3 v3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

The exit geojson worked well before I edited one of the feature's coordinates, but when I edit and add coordinates into the

```
{
     "type":"Feature",
     "id":"2",
     "properties":{  
        "name":"Brewery"
     },
     "geometry":{  
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[ 
           [
              ["13.40606689453125","12.207153501451728"],
              ["13.89495849609375","11.237674247415999"],
              ["14.401702880859375","11.545961968405738"],
              ["14.183349609375","11.962753823592042"],
              ["13.901824951171875","12.476805422291443"],
              ["13.40606689453125","12.207153501451728"]

           ]] 
     }

  }
```

streetsall.json, 
initial coordinates

```
["13.845133781433105","12.443952300713601"],
["14.112303256988524","11.964831990561656"],
["13.743875026702879","11.756096359366945"],
["13.472918272018433","12.244964223163047"],
["13.845133781433105","12.443952300713601"]
```

and open my map, it totally ruins my map! Is it that the geojson memories the initial data, and cannot edit coordinates again? Even I try to copy the new geojson in a new file it does not work. But when I return the data as initial one, it does work! I really get confused!

==========================================================================
The problem is that my new coordinates points are not in clockwise.

Comment: By ruins your map do you mean it produces errors? Doesn't draw what it is supposed to, or draws things where they aren't supposed to be? What exactly are you changing, the five coordinates in your second code block for the six in the first one?

Comment: @AndrewReid Actually there is no error and seems like the new six coordinates cover the whole path of the map.  The map is not shown as supposed to be while I am not using the five coordinates. What I can do to fix the map is just to use the geojson that before I edited(using the five coordinates)

Comment: @AndrewReid [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uhT1fOX8lWRoOLkuCc_7olpG7EMMX_HwMpV0ghYEdUg/edit?usp=sharing) here is screenshot for the map

Comment: Winding order matters in d3, if you are filling up everything except your feature, reverse the winding order (follow the right hand rule)

Comment: @AndrewReid Can you give me an example?  I can't get what you mean. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at this block: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/a7bdfeb041e850799a8d3dce4d8c50c8 , reversing the points inverts the feature.

Comment: @AndrewReid It is weird when I just fill the initial geojson nothing wrong, and when I fill another polygon which is not edited in the new geojson all goes well, but once I fill the polygon I edited all get wrong.

Comment: Odd, if your polygon is the first code block it is valid geojson - well it is if you remove the quotation marks from the coordinates, they are supposed to be numbers not strings. That could be the problem, but it would be odd if d3 drew the other polygons that also used quotations on the coordinates.

Comment: So, do you mean that the quotation marks should be removed so that D3 can read? My all coordinates are in quotation marks and worked well before I edited the geojson.

Comment: @AndrewReid Thank you so much! I figured out what's the problem! It is the order of my new coordinates. It is ok when I exchange my coordinates in clockwise.